# Pygame - Reading Font From a File Error

Tags: python, file, pygame

I made a game using pygame and want to use a certain font in the game, but when it tries reading the font file, i get an error:

" OSError: unable to read font file '/Users/tannerbeeson/Documents/Python Programs/Pygame 3.5/HOARD/crushed.ttf' "

Here's what it looks like in my code:

```
med_font=pygame.font.Font("/Users/tannerbeeson/Documents/PythonPrograms/Pygame3.5/HOARD/crushed.ttf", 45)
```

What can I do to make my game read this font file correctly?

Comment: Did you try to put the ttf file in the same directory of your game py file? If that way the error doesn't occur, you have the proof the problem is in the path.

Answer (score 0):

The problem may be that your font path argument is a relative path.

From your problem description it's not clear what your program's working directory is.  When `pygame.font.Font()` takes path "/Users/..." and tries to find the font relative to your working directory, it is likely it's looking for the font in a directory where the font isn't, or maybe the resulting absolute path doesn't even exist.  Alternatively `pygame.font.Font()` may need an absolute path for its argument.

The other (less likely) possibility is that your TTF file is corrupted since the error message says "unable to read font file".

Comment: Ok so how do I solve the problem? How do I make an "absolute" path?